# Bind DataTable to Datagrid in WPF MVVM in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm developing a WPF application with MVVM design pattern, in my first Window i want to display a datagrid that is created with the selected text of a text box [This is a preview of what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRTxV.png)

In my ViewModel I implemented a method that fill the datatable with the selectedText and then bind it to DataGrid, but My DataGrid don't show anything.
This is my method

```
 void selectColumn(object parameter)
{
    string selText = SelectedText;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(TextProperty1);
        datatable.Columns.Add("Column" + i + "");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            DataRow newRow = datatable.NewRow();

            newRow["Column" + i + ""] = line.Substring(0, selText.Length);

            datatable.Rows.Add(newRow)
        }
        i++;
    }
    else
    {

        datatable.Columns.Add("Column" + i + "");
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(TextProperty1);

        foreach (DataRow draw in datatable.Rows)
        {
            draw["Column" + i + ""] = lines[datatable.Rows.IndexOf(draw)].Substring(lines[2].IndexOf(selText), selText.Length);
        }

        TblData2 = datatable;
        i++;
    }

    TblData2 = datatable;
    TextProperty2 = TextProperty2.Remove(0, selText.Length);
}
```

and in the Window this is how i am binding Datagrid

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding TextProperty2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <i:DependencyPropertyBehavior PropertyName="SelectedText" EventName="SelectionChanged" Binding="{Binding SelectedText, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
    <Button x:Name="Tex"  Content="Select Column" Command="{Binding SelectedColumnCommand}"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DtGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding TblData2}"/>
```

This is the datatable

```
DataTable _dataTable2;
    public DataTable TblData2
    {
        get { return _dataTable2; }
        set
        {
            _dataTable2 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("TblData");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems you forgot to notify about change. Show how **property** `TblData2` is defined. It has to be property and it has to call `PropertyChanged` in setter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to enter the following code in your ViewModel.

1.Add an ObservableCollection property with all selected texts

```
ObservableCollection<string> _SelectedTexts; 

public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedTexts
{
    get { return _SelectedTexts; }
    set
    {
       _SelectedTexts; = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTexts");
    }
} 

public YourViewModelConstructor
{

    SelectedTexts = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}
```

2.Add selected text in ObservableCollection

```
public void AddSelectedText(string selectedText)
{

     SelectedTexts.Add(selectedText);


}
```

3.xaml data binding

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DtGrid"  ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTexts}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check all of the code but binding the ItemsSource to some property and then change that property at runtime will not work, you will have to use an ObservableCollection. Hope it helps.